# Looking for a short story of a medieval town where wishes were granted unintentionally

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

A friend just pointed me here after I asked this on Facebook.  I haven't had any luck there, so hopefully a more dedicated forum might help track it down. :)

> This has been bugging me for about 20 years now. I remember in 8th
>   grade, one time the teacher handed out scrap paper and the back of my
>   sheet had the first page of a short story on it that I still remember.
>   The basic premise was that there was some nebulous, potentially
>   malevolent force living under/near a medieval or fantasy type village
>   that would make wishes come true whether the wisher wanted it to be
>   true or not. To the point, the first paragraph mentioned that nobody
>   there wished anyone else "good morning", but rather just said
>   "morning" in passing, because wishing someone a good morning would
>   make it good at the expense of someone else.
>
> I don't know if there was then payment expected to the force, or it if
>   exacted payment, or if the double-edged fulfillment of the wish was
>   enough of a cost. It sort of read like a "Lottery" type vibe...
>   dystopian, social costs, etc.
>
> So... anyone have any ideas? I don't even know how I'd try to look it
>   up. To this day I usually say "morning" in passing instead of "good
>   morning" to strangers, and it always reminds me of this story. I'd
>   love to at least read the whole thing and know what it was about.

Comment: It's quite a comment trope; http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BeCarefulWhatYouWishFor

Comment: 'The World Where Wishes Worked' ?-  https://www.smashwords.com/books/view/44027.

Comment: I think you should try adding more details if you remember.

Comment: Sorry, 14111, I'll clarify, since I kind of flubbed the subject there.  What I meant was that the wish makers weren't intending for their wishes to come true.  Something as simple as "wishing" someone a good morning was granted, even without wanting it to be.  Not that the wish granter was unwilling... the wish askers were "unwilling", or at least had to be very careful.

Comment: Not medieval, but there's a partial match at http://www.hasd.org/faculty/daniellegordon/ruleofnames.pdf where magic so saturates the town that everyone is cautious with their words, including saying "morning" instead of "good morning".

Comment: Thank you internet! Well, thank you Sean. :)  This is almost certainly the story... I guess it's not medieval, but 20 years has probably clouded a few of the details in my memory.  As you can see, the first page has very little to go on. I even remember the text starting about halfway down, so I'm definitely satisfied that this is what it was.  -- And I don't see how to flag your response as an answer... that's weird.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As per my comment above, [*Rule of Names* by Ursula Le Guin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rule_of_Names) might match.

**To the point, the first paragraph mentioned that nobody there wished anyone else "good morning", but rather just said "morning" in passing, because wishing someone a good morning would make it good at the expense of someone else.**

> "Morning, Mr. Underhill," said the villagers as he passed them in the 
>   narrow street between houses with conical, overhanging roofs like the fat red 
>   caps of toadstools. "Morning, morning!" he replied to each. (It was of 
>   course bad luck to wish anyone a good morning; a simple statement of the time 
>   of day was quite enough, in a place so permeated with Influences as Sattins 
>   Island, where a careless adjective might change the weather for a week.) All of 
>   them spoke to him, some with affection, some with affectionate disdain. He 
>   was all the little island had in the way of a wizard, and so deserved 
>   respect-but how could you respect a little fat man of fifty who waddled 
>   along with his toes turned in, breathing

It is not a matter of there being a wish-granting entity, merely that magic is so prevalent in the town that it is liable to act upon the utterances of words. It is part of her Earthsea series.